# How can I customize a Bootstrap 5 container size and background color?

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-5

I have this container with a form inside of it which I am trying to customize. I am attempting to make the background of the form transparent so the background image i set is shown. For some reason the bootstrap colors and opacity dont work on this container. For example when I try bg-opacity-50 and bg-color-white it changes nothing. The following is my code for my navbar and my form under it.

```
    <body>
         
              
          <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/" class="d-block px-3 py-2 text-center bg-dark text-bold text-white old-bv">Next Upcoming event is April 1!</a>
              <!--NAVBAR-->
          <header class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark flex-column flex-md-row bd-navbar ">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                 
                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasDarkNavbar">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
            
                  <form class="d-flex mt-1 mb-1" role="search">
                      <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                      <i class="fas fa-search btn btn-success" type="submit"></i>
                     
                  </form>
                  <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>-->
          
  
                  <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start text-bg-dark "  data-bs-scroll="true" data-bs-backdrop="false" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel">
                      <div class="offcanvas-header">
                          <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel">Navigation Menu</h5>
                          <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="offcanvas-body">
                      <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                          <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                              Dropdown
                              </a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark">
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">This Event</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Past Events</a></li>
                              <li>
                                  <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                              </li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">People</a></li>
                              </ul>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </header>


          <div class="container-sm p-4 g-3 ">

            <div class="text-center row  justify-content-center ">
                <h1 class="h1 ">
                    Valentines Day Event!
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-hearts" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.931.481c1.627-1.671 5.692 1.254 0 5.015-5.692-3.76-1.626-6.686 0-5.015Zm6.84 1.794c1.084-1.114 3.795.836 0 3.343-3.795-2.507-1.084-4.457 0-3.343ZM7.84 7.642c2.71-2.786 9.486 2.09 0 8.358-9.487-6.268-2.71-11.144 0-8.358Z"/>
                    </svg>
                </h1>
              
            </div>

            <hr>
          </div>
</body>
```

I attempted to add style to it using

`background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); color:aqua;`

but for some reason this changed my text color in my form inputs.

i also tried
`background-color:red;`

and this worked to change the color but only in the middle section where my form is centered mid page. Leaving two white columns on either side of my form. I would also like to know if there is a way to remove these columns or is it not possible with a Bootstrap 5 form? I am expecting the form to only take up the space in the middle of the page unlike container-fluid which will stretch it across the page. I also want the background to be visible on the sides and only slightly visible through the transparent form in the middle. im including the background css incase it is part of the problem

```
    html { 
        background: url('img/HeartEyesEmoji.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you do it like this,

```
<div class="my-container container-fluid"> 
  <!-- your content here -->
</div>
```

css

```
.my-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1; /* set the background color */
  max-width: 800px; /* set the max-width of the container */
  margin: 0 auto; /* center the container horizontally */
  padding: 20px; /* add some padding inside the container */
}
```

Here I have added a new class "my-container"

Comment: Thank you this worked well. I just had to change the background image from the html tag to the body tag and its exactly how I wanted.